# Array of arrays insert in all rows

Tags: javascript

I have a simple piece of code below but it seems the same instance of the array is duplicated  in each row, such that when I change the value in `board[0][0]` it somehow changes it in all rows.

How can I initialize the board correctly so that each row is unique?
Looking for a sleek solution or some tweak to mine as opposed to writing out all the numbers or having a for-loop or something. Or maybe the sleekest solution is to have a for-loop?

```js
const n = 4;

let board = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(0));

board[0][0] = 1;
console.log(board)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: MDN suggests a `for` loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#using_fill_to_create_a_matrix_of_all_1

Comment: Your code is the equivalent of `var x = new Array(n).fill(0) ; let board = new Array(n).fill(x);` - so you can see how you're just filling with the same array each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new Array(n).fill(0)` is created once and then passed to `.fill` method, so indeed, you get `n` copies (references to be precise) of the same array in the result array. You could add `map` function to make `n` new arrays, like this:

```js
new Array(n).fill(0).map(x => new Array(n).fill(0));
```

In this way, `map` creates new array every time, so you get `n` different arrays filled with `0`.

Demonstration Snippet:

```js
const n = 4;

let board = new Array(n).fill(0).map(x => new Array(n).fill(0));

board[0][0] = 1;
console.log(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same reference to `new Array(n).fill(0)` is used for each filled item in the root `board` array, therefore changes to one nested array affects all others. An alternative stratergy is to use a for loop to create a different instance of nested loop for each item to fill.

```js
let board = new Array(n)
for (let i=0; i < n; i++)
    board[i] = new Array(n).fill(0);
```